# What kind of harm ends the duration of the Incite Greed spell?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, duration

The [*Incite Greed*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/incite-greed) spell's duration can be ended by my companions doing anything harmful to the afflicted targets. What is considered harmful for the purpose of the spell's duration?

> until the spell ends, or until you or your companions do anything
>   harmful to it.

In many places, the harm is defined when introduced as a term (see for examples: PHB 109; PHB 118; PHB 259). The harm here seems to be undefined, did I miss the definition here or on another page of the book?

Answer (score 11):

## It's up to your DM

"Harm" is not a game term and thus adjudicating it's meaning is not possible or intended with game rules. One  English definition for the word is "physical injury, especially that which is deliberately inflicted."

Given this, I think it's safe to say that most DMs would interpret "harm" to include, at least, damage to HP. Some DMs may take a more liberal reading of the term and include indirect forms of harm (eg inflicted conditions) and mental health into consideration as well.

So, as with any other undefined term, ask your DM.

Comment: However the term is never defined in the game and trying to build some presumed definition from other contexts in the rules is not going to help. Because it is not a defined term, there's no reason they can't use it like a normal word. Normal words have many meanings that rely on context. This book doesn't even have the same writers as the rest of the rules. So I don't think other mentions of the word have anything useful to tell us.